# checkbox determines mysqli query

Tags: php, mysql

New to php and mysqli.  I have a working php / mysqli search page with ajax for a table containing part number, description, price and quantity-in-stock.  I can write an alternate SELECT query that limits the results to items with stock > 0.
What I want is to add a checkbox on the form that allows the user to choose between  all results, or just results of items in stock (greater than zero).
I have tried to test for **stocked** using if(isset($_GET['stocked'])) but have no success.  What am I missing?  Any help is appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".search_button").click(function() {
        var search_word = $("#search_box").val();
        var dataString = 'search_word=' + search_word;

        if (search_word == '') {

        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "searchdata.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function(html) {
                    document.getElementById("insert_search").innerHTML = '';
                    $("#flash").show();
                    $("#searchword").show();
                    $(".searchword").html(search_word);
                    $("#flash").html('<img src="ajax-loader_2.gif" /> Loading Results...');
                },

                success: function(html) {
                    $("#insert_search").show();
                    $("#insert_search").append(html);
                    $("#flash").hide();
                }

            });

        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>


<form method="get" action="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="stocked" value="Yes"><label> Display in-stock items only</label>
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search_box" class='search_box'/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="search_button" />
</form>


<?php
include('dbconnect.php');
if (isset($_GET['search_word'])) {
    $search_word = $_GET['search_word'];  //get value sent from search form
    $min_length  = 2;  //2 character minimum for search
    if (strlen($search_word) >= $min_length) { // if query length is more than or equal to minimum length, then
        $search_word     = htmlspecialchars($search_word);  //change characters used in html to their equivalents
        $search_word_new = mysqli_escape_string($conn,$search_word);  //prevent SQL injection
        $search_word_fix = str_replace(" ","%",$search_word_new);
//        $raw_results     = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM stock WHERE partnumber LIKE '$search_word_fix%' AND availability > 0 ORDER BY partnumber LIMIT 10"); //in stock
        $raw_results     = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM stock WHERE partnumber LIKE '$search_word_fix%' ORDER BY partnumber LIMIT 10"); //all
        if(mysqli_num_rows($raw_results) > 0) {   //one or more rows are returned
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($raw_results)) {  //put table data into array and loop while valid
                echo "<hr class='gryhr'><br><a href=\"indexxx.php?id={$row['id']}\">{$row['partnumber']}</a><br>";          
                echo "<p>".$row['description']."<br>".
                        "List price $".$row['listprice']."<br>".
                        "In stock: ".$row['availability']."</p><br>";
            }
            echo "<hr>Total Results: " .mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
        }
        else { //no matching rows found
            echo '<div>No Results</div>';
        }
    }
    else {   // if query length less than minimum
        echo "Enter minimum of ".$min_length." characters";
    }
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Can you show us the version of your code where you were checking for `$_GET['stocked']` instead?

Comment: I have tried it several ways.

Comment: if (empty($_GET['stocked'])) {
  echo "Checked!";
} else {
  echo 'Not checked!';
}

Comment: I formatted the code but I still can't find where in that piece of code do you check `$_GET['stocked']`

Comment: Sorry.  I inserted the above test at the top of dbconnect.php just under the if (isset($_GET['search_word']))...

Comment: That should work fine (although your logic is backwards there). Are you seeing "stocked=Yes" in the URL of the page after submitting?

Comment: Good question.  I am a newbie, but I thought that since this page uses ajax to write the results, the page is not supposed to change, and the url stays the same?  Could this ajax be the real issue?   Secondly, please feel free to educate me on how the logic is backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your not sending the checkbox value to your PHP code at all ... You could do something like this:

```
    var dataString = $('#myForm').serializeObject();
    $('#myForm input[type=checkbox]').each(function() { dataString[this.name] = this.checked; });
```

You will have to modify yout script a little thought.

add id myForm to your form element and change the name of your search imput to search_word.

in a nutt shell it would look like

-- EDIT -- full code would look like this

```
<?php
// If form submited

    include('dbconnect.php');
    if (isset($_POST['search_word'])) {
        $search_word = $_POST['search_word'];  //get value sent from search form
        $min_length  = 2;  //2 character minimum for search
        if (strlen($search_word) >= $min_length) { // if query length is more than or equal to minimum length, then
            $search_word     = htmlspecialchars($search_word);  //change characters used in html to their equivalents
            $search_word_new = mysqli_escape_string($conn,$search_word);  //prevent SQL injection
            $search_word_fix = str_replace(" ","%",$search_word_new);
    //        $raw_results     = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM stock WHERE partnumber LIKE '$search_word_fix%' AND availability > 0 ORDER BY partnumber LIMIT 10"); //in stock
            if (isset($_POST['stocked'])){ $stocked = " and stocked > 0";}
            $raw_results=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM stock WHERE partnumber LIKE '$search_word_fix%' $stocked ORDER BY partnumber LIMIT 10"); //all
            if(mysqli_num_rows($raw_results) > 0) {   //one or more rows are returned
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($raw_results)) {  //put table data into array and loop while valid
                    echo "<hr class='gryhr'><br><a href=\"indexxx.php?id={$row['id']}\">{$row['partnumber']}</a><br>";          
                    echo "<p>".$row['description']."<br>".
                            "List price $".$row['listprice']."<br>".
                            "In stock: ".$row['availability']."</p><br>";
                }
                echo "<hr>Total Results: " .mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
            }
            else { //no matching rows found
                echo '<div>No Results</div>';
            }
        }
        else {   // if query length less than minimum
            echo "Enter minimum of ".$min_length." characters";
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

as for your view part

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() { // Wait until document is fully parsed

$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
   var o = {};
   var a = this.serializeArray();
   $.each(a, function() {
       if (o[this.name]) {
           if (!o[this.name].push) {
               o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
           }
           o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
       } else {
           o[this.name] = this.value || '';
       }
   });
   return o;
};

  $("#myForm").on('submit', function(e){

     e.preventDefault();

       var dataString = $('#myForm').serializeObject();
       $('#myForm input[type=checkbox]').each(function() { dataString[this.name] = this.checked; });


        if (dataString['search_word'] != '') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "searchdata.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function(html) {
                    // ...
                },

                success: function(html) {
                    $("#insert_search").show();
                    $("#insert_search").append(html);
                    $("#flash").hide();
                }

            });

        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>


<form id="myForm" action="" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="stocked" value="Yes"><label> Display in-stock items only</label>
    <input type="text" name="search_word" id="search_box" class='search_box'/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="search_button" />
</form>
```

The code you had was not working because you where sending the data using the form and you where also sending the data using ajax. You need to choose one or the other. Not both. In the above, I am sending it by ajax call and preventing the default form submit. I am also sending using POST instead of GET.

Comment: If that is the case, why is this one input not being sent when the other input in the same form is being sent.

Comment: I added the three changes above after adding the missing brackets.

Comment: There was no change.  Checkbox has no effect.

Comment: Open the developper toolbox go to network and check what the sended post looks like. is the check box in it? Also check the preview tab to see if theres an error in hadeling the request.

Comment: Opened developer tools and went to Network.  Preview looks the same as the webpage.  Console reports:   Uncaught TypeError: $(...).serializeObject is not a function  (from adding the suggested code above)

Comment: As far as I know (again I'm a newbie), I'm not writing object oriented code.  So I deleted "Object" from the statement and the error is now gone.  But the feature still does not work.

Comment: I really wana help you ... But you need to help me help you. Give me the info I need in order to understand what your facing. I am not in your head or infront of your computer. Put back the code as I sugested, give me the error and the few lines before and after the error. Edit you main question and lets solve this issue once and for all. The problem your facing is really not hard for me to solve, but with out the proper info it is. Get your stuff together and start making sense of how to ask for help.

Comment: Ok so because of the lack of cumonication I reproduced the the error and tested the code. Works on my end now. Only thing I can't reproduce is your data retreval. I edited my anwser.

Comment: I entered the changes in index.php exactly as shown, including the missing lines in the ajax.  Also changed searchdata.php as suggested.  Now clicking the Search button does nothing at all.  Even the ajax-loading gif doesn't work.  No errors.  It's just dead in the water.     I'm not experienced with how stackoverflow works.  Do I have to 'Answer Your Question' to repost updated code here?  I see no way to insert my code in a 'comment'.

Comment: Edit your original question. When you click the search button, it sends an ajax request. Check the developper tool bar at the same time. The consol can shoe js errors and the network tab can be used to check for PHP errors on the receiving end.